# Instagram pagination gow can I fix

Tags: php, pagination, call, instagram

I have a problem with instagram pagination.I need  code for media/liked.
I've tried with  $jsonurl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/useers/self/media/liked?access_token='".$data->access_token."'&count=2" but don't return anything.
Thx in advance!

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$data=$_SESSION['userdetails'];
echo $data->access_token;
if (isset($_REQUEST['next']) && isset($_SESSION['next'])) 
$jsonurl = $_SESSION['next']; 
else 
$jsonurl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/useers/self/media/liked?access_token='".$data-    >access_token."'&count=2"; 
$json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null); 
$response = json_decode($json, true); 

$_SESSION['next'] = $response['pagination']['next_url']; 
?> 
<div class="photo"> 
<a href="<?= $link ?>"><span></span><img src="<?= $thumbnail ?>" title="<?= $text ?>" alt="<?= $text ?>" /></a> 
    <div class="metaz">via <?= $author ?> at <?echo date("h:i:s A 
\o\\n d/m/Y",$date);?></div> 
    <?= $text ?>

// Button code here: 
<a href="?next">next</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling mistake in the url: `/useers/` needs to be `/users/`

`$jsonurl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/useers/self/media/liked?access_token='".$data->access_token."'&count=2";`

Needs to be:

`$jsonurl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/liked?access_token='".$data->access_token."'&count=2";`

Comment: Also, `-   >` needs to be attached as such `->`

Comment: yeah please ignore the - > and the useers

Comment: I put the code into a wordpress page...I have another code but results only 20 photos ...so I need a pagination.When I tried the code in pure php I receive the error.Warning:get_file_content.....Error 400 Bad request